# Generated DocBlocks not ending in newline character?

Tags: phpstorm

Firstly, I'm running **PHPStorm 6.0.3**. Everything's up-to-date.

I recently started using PHPStorm, and came across an annoyance that I can't seem to get to the bottom of. I like the fact that DocBlocks can be automatically generated, and when I type `/**` + `return` above a property/method/class, everything works just fine, and the comment appears like this:

```
/**
 * Class Message
 */
abstract class Message {
...
```

When I try to run `generate > PHPDoc Blocks` (through right-click context menu, CMD+N, or the "Code" menu) for an entire class, however, the DocBlocks do not honor the trailing newline character that is **definitely in the template definition** (I've checked many times). The comment block appears like this:

```
/**
 * Class Message
 */abstract class Message {
...
```

...which is rather annoying in that I have to go through and add a newline for every generated comment (above *every* property/method/class).

I've tried searching for a solution, and fiddling with settings, but nothing seems to work. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It works OK for me here on Windows 7 x64 SP1 (both PhpStorm 6.0.3 and v7 EAP). *Possibly* it is related to your code style settings (like in this case it is for functions: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12315)

Comment: @LazyOne I've spent the better part of the morning toggling settings around to try to make this work, but still no dice. Good idea though, I hadn't yet come across that ticket before

Comment: @LazyOne BINGO! I went back to the PHPDoc settings and started flipping switches again, and found the fix. I noticed that SOME of the docblocks were generated in the proper form, while others not. Disabling the options "Blank lines around parameters" *and* "Blank line before the first tag" fixed all of the issues. If you want to post an answer to this question I'll gladly accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite likely it could be because of your Code Style settings (bug in PhpStorm, if that is the case), like it is there for functions/methods: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12315

Comment: For anyone experiencing a similar issue, it was the ***Blank lines around parameters*** and ***Blank line before the first tag*** settings within ***Preferences => Code Style => PHP => PHPDoc*** that solved the issue for me.